# Siri finds images in Photos even though search has been disabled - iOS 11.4.1

Tags: iphone, siri, photos.app

I was demonstrating Siri yesterday to my friend, showing how it can search the internet for random images (show me an ***image*** of a chickadee, a Volkswagen GTI, Albert Einstein, a pressure cooker, etc.) and it was pulling images from the web until I had it search pit-bulls using the phrase "show me a ***picture*** of a pit bull."

Siri found and displayed images of my 2 pit-bulls *from the Photos app on the iPhone!* It would not find any images when I searched using the dog's names, however. When I tested this same search phrase with "German Shepherd" it found images of three other dogs in Photos, which are shepherd *mixes*, not pure breeds.

Most of the selected images were basically face-on (two eyes looking at the camera, floppy ears, etc,) but some are from the side and it found them even though pit #1 has a narrow face, pit #2 has a block-head, and none of the shepherds have the typical erect ears.

I know that facial recognition is pretty far advanced in iOS, but I had no idea it could recognize dog breeds, and I was amazed that using "show me a picture" searches the Photos app. What is more disturbing is that I deliberately set Siri not to search inside the Photos app:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue what is going on? I realize this question may be interpreted as a 'why Apple does something' query, and I will accept a downvote or two. I'll delete the question if folks think its immaterial in the long run.

I'm mystified.

Comment: I don't think this is a "why does Apple do...' question; it looks on-topic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've disabled another parameter from that menu or maybe there wasn't any menu like that before and therefore no option for that.

---

Disabling "Show Content in Search" in *Settings > Photos > Siri & Search* disables (1) Spotlight search results for Photos and (2) Siri search for Photos for me.

[image]